# an example of type erasure and my understanding

Tags: java, types, erasure

```
private void readList(ArrayList list){
    list.add("Hello");
    list.add(2);
}

public void run(){
    setFont("Courier-24");
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    readList(list);
    println("list = "+list);
    println("Type of list[1] = "+list.get(1).getClass());

}
```

**Result:**
    list = [Hello, 2]
    Type of list[1]=class java.lang.Integer

```
public void run(){
    setFont("Courier-24");
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    readList(list);
    println("list = "+list);
    println("Type of list[0] = "+list.get(0).getClass());

}
```

**Result:**
    list = [Hello, 2]
    Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

After reading something about `type erasure`, I've got my guess:
When I call `readList(list)`, it's actually adding things into list that is 'falsely' regarded as type `ArrayList` so there is no error(this is my understanding of so-called `type erasure`). But if I call `println("Type of list = "+list.get(0).getClass());` in `run()` there comes the error because `list[0]` is of type `String`(while `println("Type of list = "+list.get(1).getClass());` doesn't because list[1] is of type `Integer`). 
Is it like some criminal escaped from crime scene at first (because he belongs to normal people and normal people has freedom), and later when police start to check everyone that was around then he got caught because he is a criminal in deep?

Comment: *"Is it like some criminal escaped from crime scene at first (because he belongs to normal people and normal people has freedom), and later when police start to check everyone that was around then he got caught because he is a criminal in deep?"* Yes, it's like that.

Answer (score 1):

To go along `type erasure` principles your method should look like

```
private void readList(ArrayList<Integer> list){
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
}
```

It will be apparent that adding a string to array of integers is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
private void readList(ArrayList list){
```

that isn't type erasure. It is an example of a [`raw type`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). Per the Java Tutorials,

> A *raw type* is the name of a generic class or interface without any type arguments.

before generics were added to Java there were only *raw types*.

In constrast [type-erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) is an optimization. Generics are a compile time type check feature, there is no *performance* impact because the generic types **are not**<sup>1</sup> checked at run-time.

<sup>1</sup> There is a type cast inserted in the byte code.